# How to implement a kafka consumer that process after 2 parallel consumers finish their task

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 2 Kafka consumers (groups) who process parallel from a topic. They emit their result to a topics as message.
Now I want to implement a kafka consumer that should take the 2 results (that were computed from one message) and aggregate it. As this is more a stateful processing how will I to implement a Kafka consumer (spring boot) coordinate the completion of the up stream consumers?
I know such things can be implemented in `Apache Flink`, Kafka streams and other such framework, though would like to see if other options exists.

[image: The processing diagram]

Comment: You'd need to join the records of A and B on a common value, then consume to C processor. Otherwise, you'd need to setup distributed locks / code "circuit breakers" to run when all conditions are met

Answer (score 0):

Key the result output by a common key, and sub each result with a result counter and total expected. The consumer, then for each key, just needs to wait until it's received the expected number. You can do this with Kafka Streams easily. This is a sort of water mark pattern.